# How to use IIS URL Rewrite with gzip compression

Tags: iis-7.5, rewrite, gzip

I've been trying to create outbound rules in IIS 7.5 on Windows 2008 R2 on a site that has static HTML pages and compression enabled.

If I have any form of compression enabled (static or dynamic) I get this error:

```
HTTP Error 500.52 - URL Rewrite Module Error. Outbound rewrite rules cannot
be applied when the content of the HTTP response is encoded ("gzip").
```

Turning off compression is not really an option due the large negative impact that would have on page load performance.

I imagine anyone who uses outbound rewrite rules is going to run into this error, as you would always want compression enabled for textual content.

I've looked at some suggestions to get this to work:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3713804/url-rewrite-outbound-rules-iis7/4363301#4363301

and

http://forums.iis.net/p/1165899/1937454.aspx#1937454

But I still get the same error.

Has anyone got this to work? If so how?

Comment: I have another problem...http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30806106/simple-iis-rewrite-outbound-rule-is-giving-an-error-and-page-crashes

Comment: Why are you using outbound rewrite rules? Can you provide a sample of one of these rules for context? Perhaps a normal rewrite rule will suffice?

Answer (score 3):

Please refer :https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/friis/2016/08/25/iis-with-url-rewrite-as-a-reverse-proxy-part-2-dealing-with-500-52-status-codes/

Outbound rewrite rules cannot be applied when the content of the HTTP response is encoded ("gzip").

This is because the responses that are coming from the back end server are using HTTP Compression, and URL rewrite cannot modify a response that is already compressed. This causes a processing error for the outbound rule resulting in the 500.52 status code.

Answer (score 0):

Rewrite 2.0 cannot modify HTML output if the data is already compressed.

People disable compression by resetting `Accept-Encoding` (of by setting it to `Accept-Encoding: identity`):

```
<serverVariables>
   <set name="HTTP_ACCEPT_ENCODING" value="" />
</serverVariables>
```

Another approach is getting rid of hacky HTML data rewrites:

```
<outboundRules>
    <rule name="HtmlRspRewriteOutboundRule" preCondition="HtmlRspRewriteCond" enabled="true">
        <match filterByTags="A, Form, Img" pattern="^http(s)?://internal.example.com:8080/(.*)" />
        <action type="Rewrite" value="http{R:1}://app.example.com/{R:2}" />
    </rule>
</outboundRules>
```

and replace them with binding all app URLs to **unmovable context prefix**, like `/app` so **all the links are from the server root with a given prefix**. **You omit HTTP/HTTPS protocol, server host name and port**! This way you rewrite only `Host` response header: **headers are not compressed, so you avoid the specified error**!

Remember that HTTP URLs could be embedded into CSS & JS files too and it is a nihjtmare to correctly rewrite them. Work with **URLs relative to server root instead**!